# Setting pre-hook for docker-compose file

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am running a dockerized django app and I am looking for a way to run (a) directive(s) every time before I build a docker container. More concretely, I would like to run `docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py check --deploy` each time before I either build or up the production.yml file and stop the build process if any erroroccur. Like a pre-hook.

I know I could achieve this with a bash-script, yet I was wondering if there is a way of doing this inside the docker-compose file. I can't find anything in the docker documentation (except events, but I don't understand if they serve for what I want to achieve) about it and I assume that this is not possible. Yet, maybe it is in fact possible or maybe there is a hacky workaround?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#custom-build-phase-hooks

Comment: Thank you iklinac for that hint! I didn't see that. Yet, follwowing your advice I am creating a folder ``hooks/pre_build`` and insert ``#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "=> Build the site" python manage.py check --deploy --fail-level=CRITICAL`` . But it still builds my container and doesn't show me anything. I tried placing it in the root folder and at the same level as my dockerfile. Also assuming this works, would this stop my container from building if there are warnings? Because I would like to **not** build the container if the pre_build fails

Comment: @iklinac, did you ever try this? Considering this issue is still open https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6982 , it doesn't seem like docker has that options

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, **this is not possible**. There have been multiple requests to add such functionality, but the maintainers do not consider this a good idea.

See:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/468
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1341
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6736

Comment: Thanks istepaniuk! Yes, at the end I had to do it with bash-scripts.